# Display color in a JavaFX TableRow

Tags: colors, javafx, tablerow

I would like to change the color of the text displayed in a TableRow.
The instruction setStyle("-fx-background-color: green"); is working well,
but the instruction setTextFill doesn't work. Is it normal ?

```
tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> param) {
        final TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<Person>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                setTextFill(Color.RED);
                //setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
            }
        };
        return row;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set the default CSS file in your application with:

```css
 .cell {
   -fx-background-color: #FFCCAA;
   -fx-text-fill: #000000;
 }
  /*   if you want more different colours for even and odds:  */
 .cell:odd {
   -fx-background-color: #FFDDDD;
   -fx-text-fill: green;
 }
```

You can add this file.css to your scene:

```java
scene.getStylesheets().add("file.css");
```